# How to clean <p:dataTable> globalFilter field?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the following requirement:

In case the user push one of the paginator buttons and there is a value in the `globalFilter` `inputText` then the value should be deleted.

This is the table (lazy loading):

```
  <p:dataTable id="osTable"
        var="os" 
        value="#{bean.lazyModel}" 
        selection="#{bean.selectedObjectSet}" 
        selectionMode="single"
        rowKey="#{os.ID}"
        paginator="true"
        paginatorPosition="bottom"
        paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
        rows="10"
        widgetVar="table">
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <p:outputPanel style="float: right">  
                <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" 
                             value="#{bean.find}" 
                             onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {table.filter()}" 
                             style="width:150px">

                </p:inputText>
            </p:outputPanel>  
        </f:facet>
```

I guess I need to do that via javascript but I don’t know how to implement this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<p:ajax event="page" oncomplete="jQuery('#yourFormID\\:yourDataTableID\\:globalFilter').val('')"/>
```

this should clean the filter on pagination complete....

Comment: I don’t know why but this solution is working only when the p:inputText is not inside the table. 
When i am adding the inputText in the table (globalFilter) for some reason the table id is not recognize.

Thanks

Comment: I did check the source and it's look correct but still I it’s not working("Message: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: osTable").
Thanks for the help

Comment: try to just use - jQuery('#globalFilter').val(''); This just scans the whole dom for the globalFilter property id. The above example enforces wwhere to find it (ie, youf formID then into yourDataTableID which would be ( osTable ).

Comment: @VeenarM, and if you more than one table?

Comment: @Daniel - Well then sure be more explicit :) more than one table ot a page would look clutter imo but each to there own :)